# sqlserver 2005 sp3 poor performance and scheduled job failing

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, hardware-raid

When executing the Microsoft SQL Server 2005 `best practices analyzer`, I am getting some reported as follow:

> The Outdated system driver [C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntoskrnl.exe] of System that can cause paging detected.

How can I fix the above-mentioned outdated driver?

> Disk sector [0] alignment of server is not configured optimally. work with their hardware vendor on optimal settings.In order to fix this potential issue, you will have to recreate and reformat the suboptimally aligned partition. "Hard disk sectors are optimally configured to have a starting offset of 64 KB or a multiple of 64 KB. Hard disk sectors were  detected that have starting offsets that differ from this configuration. For RAID volumes, which are made of multiple physical spindles, this can adversely affect I/O response time.

And what about the alignment issue on my blade server with RAID 1?  At this point, I don't have any idea which Windows patch or hotfix has to be installed to resolve this issue.

I am also getting a large performance impact on the end users and `sqlserv.exe`. Windows 2003 has high CPU utilization, as well as especially high disk read and write I/O.

My scheduled job process has always failed. Is there an issue with the either RAID 1 or Windows 2003?

Regards,
Elango

Answer (score 1):

`ntoskrnl.exe` is the actual operating system kernel, so you can't replace that "driver" without reinstalling/upgrading the operating system.

If you experience poor SQL Server performance while disk I/O is high, you probably need to replace your disk subsystem. It's good practice to use `RAID10` for database systems, and also to separate the SQL Server data from the operating system (i.e. put your database on a different volume on different disks than the OS). Did you already implement the recommendations made [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180922%28v=sql.105%29)?

As for the disk sector alignment issue, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). The information should be applicable to SQL Server 2005 as well.

Comment: The recommendations have not been followed by the guys who are installed the sql database on the windows server, i noticed that the datafile,log file and backup file are in the same volume ,i guess the poor performance due to this. Surely i will tune the database and virtual memory accordingly.

Comment: how can i check that the sql server database is being backed up properly,up to date? how can proceed the process of put the data,backup and log files in the different path and volume which are currently in the same volume because i am concerned about the I/O performance. or can i backup the manually ? please suggest me .also should my hardware RAID 0 may cause the read and write disk performance issue? Thanks in advanced.  Regards,Elango

Comment: Backups should be recorded in the SQL Server logs. Moving the location of databases and transaction logs is described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071). RAID0 should give you max. performance, but is terrible from an availability perspective (it roughly doubles the chance of a disk failure). Also RAID controller model and RAID config can affect performance a lot. This isn't the right place for teaching DB basics, though. Microsoft has *vast* amounts of [SQL Server documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), so I suggest you start there.